# Accessing another view in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Here I have tried to get connected with the server. It says CONNECTION SUCCESSFUL. What I want to know is that that how can I go to another view when connection is successful?
I am a newbie please give your suggestion.. ?

here is the login button code

```
-(IBAction)loginButton:(id)sender
{
    NSString *uName = [userName text];
    NSString *pWord = [password text];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:uName forKey:@"uName"];
    [defaults setObject:pWord forKey:@"pWord"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    NSLog(@"Data Saved");
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&Username=%@&Password=%@", userName.text, password.text];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postlength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myurl"]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postlength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if(conn){
        if(conn){
            MainView *mainView = [[MainView alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainScreen" bundle:nil];
            self.mView = mainView;
        }
        NSLog(@"Connection successful");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Connection failed");
    }   
}
```

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the new view as a subview to show it. This will work if the class calling is the main view controller class:

```
if(conn){
        MainView *mainView = [[MainView alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainScreen" bundle:nil];
        self.mView = mainView;
       [self.view addSubview: mainView.view];
    }
```

Comment: I guess if `MainView` has `initWithNibName` method - it is not a UIView subclass.

Comment: Whats the name of the view you added? Its possible to add "mainView" as a subview of it.

Comment: [MainScreen.view addSubview: mainView.view];

Comment: its not working... Is there would be the issue with different names like my view controller class has named MainView and xib file name is MainScreen ??

Comment: here I have one more question, what if I want to get the data from the server and want to save it to view. How can i do that ?

Comment: Pretty complex question. You might consider asking a new question about it.

Comment: my new question is at:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325147/getting-xml-file-from-server-and-then-parsing-it

Answer (score 0):

If you have UINavigationController into your project try this:

```
if(conn){
    MainView *mainView = [[MainView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainScreen" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mainView animated:YES];
    [mainView release];
}
```

Comment: No, i have added a simple view

Comment: view or viewController? `initWithNibName` indicates that you have created an UIViewController.

Comment: MainView is a UIViewController Subclass and a view is added