# Getting XML file from server and then parsing it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to download XML file from a specific URL and then want to parse it to see the data received and if the data is received properly then I want my application to change its view from login screen to other screen.
Here is the code I am using:

-(IBAction)entButton:(id)sender
{
    NSString *uName = [userName text];

```
NSString *pWord = [password text];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults setObject:uName forKey:@"uName"];

[defaults setObject:pWord forKey:@"pWord"];

[defaults synchronize];

NSLog(@"Data Saved");

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&Username=%@&Password=%@", userName.text, password.text];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postlength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myurl"]]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[request setValue:postlength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if(conn){

    if(conn){

        MainView *mainView = [[MainView alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainScreen" bundle:nil];

        self.mView = mainView;

        [self.view addSubview: mainView.view];
    }

    NSLog(@"Connection successful");
}

else{

    NSLog(@"Connection failed");
}
```

}

thanx!

Answer (score 0):

//connection delegate then use the parser delegate with the class inheriting NSXMLParserDelegate

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    [theConnection release];
    xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:receivedData];
    MapLoading *objMapLoading=[[MapLoading alloc]init];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:objMapLoading];
    [xmlParser parse];
}


-  (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser;  
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict;            
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName;
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string;
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser;
```

in parserDidEndDocument create the data for UILoading.

Answer (score -1):

In that case you can call 
MainView *mainView = [[MainView alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainScreen" bundle:nil];

```
    self.mView = mainView;

    [self.view addSubview: mainView.view];
```

in NSURLConnection delegate method
   connectionDidFinishLoading

Comment: it is not the answer what i need to know